# blockchain transactions dump file

Tags: transactions, blockchain, logging

I am looking for hourly, daily, weekly, monthly and yearly blockchain transactions dump in csv or other formats. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can take a look on www.kaiko.com

Comment: Could you please add a little explanation on what service kaiko offers and why it solves the asker's question?

Comment: I agree with @Murch.  This answer may be exactly what the OP is looking for, so I don't want to vote to delete it.  However, without any context provided, it's a poor answer that is easily mistaken for spam.  A good answer should explain itself, and not just link elsewhere.